# Query Kibana from javascript to change the graph

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana

I am plotting graph using kibana iframe tag on my webpage
I am trying to query kibana or elasticsearch to plot the graph when a field is equal to given value.

I know I can query ES for a field having a given value but how to change kibana graph based on the received data. 
Basically I want to filter kibana like field (A = 20) and with this graph should get change.